# When does knowledge become wisdom

Tags: knowledge

I am curious about wisdom, I was questioning myself if I could figure out what is wisdom, and I guess wanted to go with obvious answer and conected wisdom with knowledge, but this is not one to one ratio. In my mind people hold both wisdom and knowledge and books can only hold knowledge. So by certain logic I get to conclusion that if wisdom is written down in a book it becomes knowledge. and this is my confusion, I wonder if this is safe assumption and what does it take for knowledge from a book to become wisdom once again, as I am certain in my mind that just by reading a piece of knowledge one is not granted with wisdom.

Comment: What sort of answer are you hoping for here? Could you share a little bit about what your research has uncovered so far?

Comment: Knowledge is quantifiable while wisdom is qualifiable. In other words, knowledge is measurable to some extent, whereas wisdom is a *trait or attribute* signifying one's intellectual skill in processing knowledge.

Comment: Intelligence is knowing there is more than one option. Wisdom is choosing one.